# upgrade to newer version manage categories not showing in admin menu

Tags: menu, submenu

upgrading to newer version now we do not have the manage categories in the menu I tried hard to find where I should insert or change anything for example adminhtml.xml or config.xml
I thought maybe some modules made this to happen but I disabled all modules and still I cannot see it in the menu the magento upgrade version is from 12 to 13 
is there anyone experiencing the same?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem my self it was from :

```
app/code/core/Enterprise/catalogEvent/etc/adminhtml.xml
```

the menu structure is in XMl and we can find tag of `<categories>` by clicking the folder in eclipse and search in selected resources 
the categories tag was disabled 
something like this:

```
<categories>
<disabled>1<disabled>
```

so I just deleted it